# Я не понимаю, где(,) по мнению автора(,) проходит граница...

Tags: вводные-слова

***Я не понимаю, где(,) по мнению автора(,) проходит граница*** [между "можно" и "нельзя"]...

Рука отказывается ставить эти запятые. Не вижу здесь *источника* информации, вижу саму "информацию", без которой фраза теряет смысл.

Разбираться некогда, просто скажите для начала, есть ли хоть малейшая возможность считать этот оборот в данном контексте не вводным?!

Answer (score 1):

Не видно такой возможности: без обособления это выражение даже приводит к ложному смыслу прохождения границы по просторам мнения автора (дипломатичный вариант указания на геометрическое место точек в его мозгу). Здесь можно усмотреть источник информации, запрашиваемый, пусть и без надежды, риторическим вопросом (хотелось бы, чтобы *автор сообщил* своё мнение на этот счёт - сам я теряюсь в догадках).

Comment: Я котов сообщить вам мнение по любому вопросу, если имею его. Но я не понимаю, о чем вы спрашиваете. Какая еще граница? Риторический вопрос и/или источник информации - да, возможно.

Answer (score 0):

**Я не понимаю, где, по мнению автора, проходит граница...**

**Я не вижу особой смысловой разницы** между значением необособленной падежной формы "по твоему мнению" и её обособленным вариантом, который относят к вводным словам.

Поэтому **авторы практически единогласно обособляют словосочетание как вводное слово,** так как **этого требуют правила**, а структура предложения обычно позволяет это сделать. Это такое традиционное написание, над которым вряд ли кто  задумывается.

Только в самых простых высказываниях (когда паузу делать неудобно,  а логическим ударением надо выделить  оборот, обозначая вопросительную интонацию) может встретиться необособленный вариант, например: **А это что по твоему мнению?**

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

Вы видите, что, **по мнению автора**, источник нравственных побуждений Вронского ― пустые общественные предрассудки.

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F7%F2%EE+%EF%EE+%EC%ED%E5%ED%E8%FE+%E0%E2%F2%EE%F0%E0

Answer (score 0):

Убрать проблему двусмысленности этой фразы, не обособляя оборот (граница проходит по мнению автора), можно лишь его изменив, хотя бы так: «Я не понимаю, где с точки зрения автора проходит граница».

Без изменения слов и первоначального их порядка возможно лучшим решением — на письме, разумеется, на слух фраза двусмысленность сохранит, — могут быть скобки: «Я не понимаю, где (по мнению автора) проходит граница».

Comment: Во фразе нет двусмысленности. Есть, на мой взгляд, вопрос об обособлении.